# JavaScript: show/hide elements on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few sections of text that I need to show/hide when I click on the title. So far, I have only managed to show or hide them all at once, but not individually  (i.e. click on Title 1, hide Text Section 1 etc.). How do I go about this ?

This is what I have:

```
<div class="content">

            <div class="title"><a href="#">Section 1</a>        
            </div>

            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
            </div>

            <div class="title"><a href="#">Section 2</a>    
            </div>

            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
            </div>

            <div class="title"><a href="#">Section 3</a>
            </div>

            <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
            </div>

        </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('.title').click(function(){
            $('.text').toggle();
});

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show hide html div using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473096/show-hide-html-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `this` to refer to the element being clicked. So in your case `$(this).next('.text').toggle();`:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.title').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.text').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title"><a href="#">Section 1</a>
</div>

<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
</div>

<div class="title"><a href="#">Section 2</a>
</div>

<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
</div>

<div class="title"><a href="#">Section 3</a>
</div>

<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I was experimenting with "this" and "next" but wasn't sure how to use it.